# Does gRPC support zeromq or nanomsg?

Tags: zeromq, grpc, nanomsg

According to the [gRPC.io website](https://grpc.io/about/) I know gRPC supports http 1.x and 2.0 but what about other "transports" like zeromq or nanomsg?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gRPC does not support zeromq or nanomsg. The supported transports are [HTTP2, QUIC and in-process](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/tree/master/src/core/ext/transport). You can find more details in https://grpc.github.io/grpc/core/md_doc_core_transport_explainer.html